# Gauge framework - information about test failure in runtime

Tags: python, selenium, getgauge

I'm using python and Gauge framework.
I need to perform some action in @after_scenario only when scenario fails.

I've tried to dig in the framework in search of related property and I found following one:

```
Scenario.is_failing
```

After printing it on a console in after_scenario I woud expect true/false, but instead of this I can see:

```
<property object at 0x000002600477F060>
```

Could you please explain me why is that and what can I do to get simple true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be looking at the current execution context. Example:
`print(context[.specification | .scenario].is_failing)`

Python code for getting whether the current specification and current scenario is failing.

```
@after_scenario
def after_scenario_hook(context):
    print(f'Specification is failing: {context.specification.is_failing}')
    print(f'Scenario is failing: {context.scenario.is_failing}')
```

Same, but Java.

```
    @AfterScenario
    public void afterGaugeScenario(ExecutionContext context) {
        System.out.println("Specification is failing: " + context.getCurrentSpecification().getIsFailing());
        System.out.println("Scenario is failing: " + context.getCurrentScenario().getIsFailing());
    }
```